# Error while configuring CMake project: Running 'nmake' '-?' failed

Tags: c, cmake, nmake

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/compile.html) for building GLFW on Windows, and I'm getting the error when running `cmake -S . -B Build`:

```
PS ~\glfw-3.3.2\GLFW> cmake -S . -B Build
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   The system cannot find the file specified


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "~/glfw-3.3.2/GLFW/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Output log is almost completely empty containing only one line with my windows version.
I haven't found any discussions or problems matching mine. And I don't even know does nmake have `-?` flag since it's not listed on microsoft docs site.

I've tried positioning in other folder because maybe that's the case. But with no luck.

I tried solving it with other error solution's but to no avail.

Comment: "And I don't even know does nmake have `-?` flag" - This is easy to check: just run `nmake -?` in the terminal.

Comment: The thing is running `nmake -?` results in 
`'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`
And you can think that maybe I need to install `nmake` but cmake works normally for other projects I've written myself and when I just tried to build GLFW the error appeared with no reason whatsoever.

Comment: "cmake works normally for other projects I've written myself" - Probably, for other projects you have used [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) other than `NMake Makefiles`. E.g. you have used Visual Studio for those successful projects.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe I haven't used any generators as you said. I wrote CmakeLists.txt according to a tutorial in my project and used cmake command to run it. I code in VSC so maybe there is a generator used somewhere not sure. But I did encounter this error while writing my makefiles and it kinda solved it self after configuring CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER flag and in this GLFW project I did also configure that flag but this time it did not help. Maybe error lies somewhere else I'm looking into it and hopefully I'll find an answer. Thanks for suggestions where to look. :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution was to append `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` to `cmake -S . -B Build` command. As [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) suggested I looked more into generators and found out that setting the flags doesn't imply which generator will be used. So manually setting the flags solved the problem for me.

Comment: I am getting the error while running python command "pip install -r requirements.txt" while installing dependency llama-cpp-python. Can some one tell me where to use -G "MinGW Makefiles"   option in pip install command

Answer (score 6):

The error is about absent `nmake` utility, which is a build tool for CMake projects configured with "NMake Makefiles" [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

You need either to install `nmake`, or specify (with `-G` option) other generator, which is available on your platform (Windows) and for which you have a built tool. Possible selection of other generators includes e.g. "MinGW Makefiles" and "Visual Studio" family.